# How to use odbc connectivity in android for accessing access database

Tags: android, ms-access, odbc

I want some idea that how to use odbc connectivity for accessing Access database .

I did some search i got one link :

http://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb01038.html.

If anyone having any idea about that then please revert.

Comment: using JDBC/ODBC directly on android? [i got a better idea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yldLSmzXns&t=0m29s) use REST service for this

Comment: i just want to use odbc connection for that

Comment: Are you talking about establishing a direct ODBC connection to a remote Access database via the data connection on a mobile device? If so, then that is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @Kirti: MS Access is not mobile friendly. since its a file based database every time when you access the DB, you have to wait until the file is opened>> huge load time. hence people above me didn't recommend it. if you want to do this for test purpose, you need to create machine jdbc:odbc driver described like hier: http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/jdbc-access-gateway/getting-started.html

Comment: The fact that JET/ACE is file based HAS ZERO to do with load times. The time to open a table with 1 row, or a million rows is the same. You are likely new to computers, or don’t understand how file based database engines work. As noted, the link to the jdbc access gate way STILL requires that you have a working version of JET/ACE on the given platform for ODBC to work.

Comment: @krish do you having any idea about using that jdbc:odbc driver?

Comment: @Gord Thompson why it is not a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You not only need a ODBC driver, but one that is spiecif for the JET (now called ACE) database engine. In other words you need a driver that includes the database engine, and I not aware that a version of JET/ACE exists for Android.

So when you connect to a ODBC source, you need a specific ODBC driver that includes the JET/ACE code (database engine). Since a version of JET/ACE does not exist for Android then this is not possible to my knowledge. So the jdbc driver will work on the windows platform because you have use of the JET/ACE .dll's that also work on windows. Such a set of dll's or a version of the JET/ACE engine does not exist for Android. You likely best connect to a server based system, and then have something on the windows desktop that pulls this data into the JET/ACE file format. You could also perhaps just use XML or csv files, and again have some windows desktop code pull data from that file into Access.